# Merge 2 tables in mysql to display as one

Tags: php, sql

I have  2 tables that 1 want to merge as one. I am using php and mysql.

```
Table Reservation

reservationid  checkin       checkout
   1           2017-01-01     2017-01-03
   2           2017-01-10     2017-01-20
   3           2017-02-05     2017-02-08

Table RoomReserve

reservationid    roomnumber
 1                 1
 2                 100
 2                 101
 3                 1
 3                 2
 3                 3
```

How can i merge these 2 tables to get this table:

```
reservationid   checkin        checkout     roomnumber
    1           2017-01-01     2017-01-03      1
    2           2017-01-10     2017-01-20      100
    2           2017-01-10     2017-01-20      101
    3           2017-02-05     2017-02-08      1
    3           2017-02-05     2017-02-08      2
    3           2017-02-05     2017-02-08      3
```

Please note that this merge table is for display in admin page. 
How can i do that?

Comment: The SQL keyword you're looking for is: `JOIN`

Comment: Just `LEFT JOIN` two tables and remember to specify the table you are selecting or shearching from like this `tablename.index`

Comment: Hint: `JOIN`.  If you don't know how to join a table, I suggest you stop working on it, and let someone else who know what they're doing to do it.

Comment: can we use natural join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could apply `join`.

```
select r.reservationid,r.checkin,r.checkout,rr.roomnumber from reservationtable r inner join 
roomreserver rr on r.reservationid = rr.reservationid
```